# How to install multiple packages into a namespace like group in Pacman?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, package-management, pacman

What I mean is to install similar packages into a namespace, which I can uninstall with a single command.

Lets say I want to Install some packages which are used for a certain thing, which doesn't depend on other packages installed.
`pacman -S package1 package2 package3`

In future I may install `package4, package5, etc.`.

But when I need to uninstall these packages I may forget to uninstall some packages which are independently usable. So is there a way to group packages into a namespace or group when installing and uninstall all the packages installed in that namespace?

Eg:

Install package1, package2, package3 into "packages" namespace

`pacman -S --namespace "packages" package1 package2 package3`

Then Install package4, package5 into "packages" namespace

`pacman -S --namespace "packages" package4 package5`

Uninstall every packages in "packages" namespace

`pacman -Rsu --namespace "packages"`

So is there any way I can do this with multiple namespaces which contains packages for similar usage?

Comment: I don't see anything like this in the manpage. Why not just save the package names into a directory with each "namespace" in its own file?

Comment: @muru, can you please explain me with examples on how to do that?